# How can I obtain system arguments in node.js?

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments

```
node helloworld.js alex
```

I want it to console.log() alex.  How do I pass "alex" as an argument into the code?

In python ,it is `sys.argv[1]`

Answer (score 4):

You can access command line arguments using `process.argv` in node.js.

The array also includes the node command and the application file, so the first custom command line argument will have an index = 2.

```
process.argv[2] === 'alex'; // true
```

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv

Comment: Jørgen is right, but mind that "alex" is `process.argv[2]` in the example.

Comment: Thanks, I included it in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements are more complex and you can take advantage of a command line argument parser, there are several choices. Two that seem popular are

- https://www.npmjs.org/package/minimist (simple and minimal)
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/nomnom (option parser with generated usage and commands)

More options available at [How do I pass command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js)