# How to add a parameter to mkdir?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm trying to automate and create a directory inside of the existing directory *beatles*, how to parameterize the following?

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mkdir $(echo beatles/$1)"
  },
```

I tested that but that doesn't work:

```
 npm run test ringo
```

It should create directory *ringo* inside of an existing directory named *beatles*:

```
 beatles/ringo
```

Comment: `mkdir -p beatles/$1` should create all the path elements as necessary. I have no idea what the complication of the `$(echo ...)` subshell is for.

Comment: @thrig I tried the simplest way first, it doesn't work too `mkdir beatles/$1`

Comment: @Mikel the parameter though is unix-centric

Comment: @Hao, please specify which *shell*, (i.e. `bash`, `csh`, `zsh`, `sh`, etc.), your code is meant to run under.

Answer (score 0):

I guess parameters can't be inlined to unix commands when using npm, based on this answer..

[NPM run script pass argument from one script to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714520/npm-run-script-pass-argument-from-one-script-to-another)

..npm appends the parameter to scripts.

The only way the parameters can be inlined in the command is invoking it via separate script. I created this create-dir.sh

```
mkdir beatles/$1
```

And changed the npm script:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "./create-dir.sh"
},
```

And then running this..

```
npm run test ringo
```

..the directory ringo is created inside of something directory

If there's any other approach I would be glad to know