# Use parameters from Jenkins and pass to JS conf file

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I would like to pass a parameter from Jenkins into my `baseURL:` value in my protractor conf file. Is this possible? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it from the *command-line* when starting protractor:

```
protractor protractor.conf.js --baseUrl="http://127.0.0.1:900"
```

Comment: will this work if the command I run is `npm run <test name>` ?

Comment: @DarthOpto yeah, you can pass arguments with `npm run`, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script.

Comment: We are actually using the following command with npm. `npm run e2e-bvt -- --baseUrl=http://$URL --suite=$TESTSUITE_NAME --capabilities.browserName=$BROWSER`