# How to pass parameters from npm command to protractor config file

Tags: npm, protractor

How to pass parameters from npm command to protractor config file

I have protractor config file:

```
exports.config = {

allScriptsTimeout : 30000,

suites : {        
   login2 : 'e2e/TestSuites/Full/LoginTestSuite/ValidInvalidLogins.js',
},
// configure multiple browsers to run tests
multiCapabilities : [
{
   'browserName' : 'chrome'
    //'browserName': 'firefox'
} ],
baseUrl :'http://localhost:8080',
framework : 'jasmine2',
jasmineNodeOpts : {
    defaultTimeoutInterval : 30000
 },
};
```

and npm package.json file :

```
 "scripts": {   
"e2e-bvt": "protractor tests/protractor-conf-BVT.js --baseUrl $baseUrl",    
 },
```

I want to pass --baseUrl = http://testurl:8080 to npm command so that protractor config file can take this parameter to run test against different baseUrl.

how can I achieve something like:

```
 npm run e2e-bvt --$baseUrl=http://testurl:8080
```

Comment: when I am executing this its throwing error: `invalid element state: Failed to execute 'replace' on 'Location': '$baseUrl#/Account/LogIn' is not a valid URL.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add "--" next to your npm run command and then pass all required parameters.

```
  "scripts": {   
      "e2e-bvt": "protractor tests/protractor-conf-BVT.js",    
  }
```

> npm run e2e-bvt -- --baseUrl=http://testurl:8080

the above command will take all the argumnets (--baseUrl=http://testurl:8080) and pass this argument to the script e2e-bvt.

Comment: Thanks @Sudharsan this helped.

Comment: Also you can pass other params as well (i am using to debug locally with different users). Just check this line in config - https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L280

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing arguments to the script correctly. Let's apply [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356509/771848):

```
baseUrl="http://testurl:8080" npm run e2e-bvt
```

Comment: Tried running above command and it gives `'baseUrl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.` I am running this from windows machine.