# How to use variables in npm scripts on windows

Tags: npm

I've got a bare repository from which we start new projects. Inside this repository is another repository that has to be updated seperately. Every project starts with these two repositories, but sometimes during the project they should not both be updated.

I'm trying to create an Npm script that clones the parent repository, after that it opens the folder and clones the child repository.

The script has a variable that represents the project and thus folder name.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356509/5127982), I came up with the following:

```
"new_project": "git clone x:/parent_repo $PROJECT & cd $PROJECT & git clone x:/child_repo"
```

I run the command like so: `PROJECT=new_project_name npm run new_project` 
Have also tried `PROJECT="new_project_name" npm run new_project`

**Unfortunately this creates a folder named `$PROJECT` in stead of actualy reading the variable.**

Also tried:

```
"new_project": "git clone x:/parent_repo $PROJECT & cd $PROJECT & git clone x:/child_repo"

npm run new_project --PROJECT new_project_name
```

or run with

```
npm run new_project -- --PROJECT=new_project
```

Same result.

Most of these sollutions seem to work on linux machines but not for Windows.

It appears the variables in the string are not being read as such. I tried

```
"git clone x:/parent_repo "+$PROJECT+" & cd "+$PROJECT+" & git clone x:/child_repo"
```

But that just gave me syntax errors.

How do I succesfully pass a variable from the command line that I can use in my npm script?

The command has to be a single line.

*I'm using Git bash on windows as cli*

*npm version: 2.14.20*

Comment: @zerohero 2.14.20

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, [the answer I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356509/5127982) which was not working, seemed to fail on my machine because of a difference in operating systems.

This works on Linux:

`"new_project": "git clone x:/parent_repo $PROJECT & cd $PROJECT & git clone x:/child_repo"`

`PROJECT=new_project_name npm run new_project`

To get this to work on Windows, you need to escape the variable with `% %` in stead of `$`. Also you need to specificaly SET the variable on the windows cli. To combine with the script, you need to link the script and the set variable command with `&&`.

So the above on Windows becomes:

`"new_project": "git clone x:/parent_repo %PROJECT% & cd %PROJECT% & git clone x:/child_repo"`

`SET PROJECT=new_project_name && npm run new_project`

Also note, if you want to refer to the config variables you have to escape that variable in the same way. So `$npm_package_config_yourvariable` becomes `%npm_package_config_yourvariable%` on Windows.

Comment: In Windows it seems `SET` to use a variable, but how I can use this variable... This simple code doesn't work: `SET APPVERSION=%npm_package_version% && echo App Version = $APPVERSION`. I tried with $APPVERSION and %APPVERSION% and no one works.

Comment: @Gabrielizalo is should be `%APPVERSION%` but I'm not sure if you can set a variable with another variable i.e. `%npm_package_version%`

Comment: in npm version >6 this has stopped working. not sure why, or how to resolve variables in npm-scripts on windows now... :(

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `package.json` config.

```
{
    "name" : "myapp",
    "config" : { "folder": "myfolder" },
    "scripts" : {
        "new_project": "git clone x:/parent_repo $npm_package_config_folder & cd $npm_package_config_folder & git clone x:/child_repo"
    }
}
```

Then :

```
npm config set myapp:folder mynewfolder

npm run newproject
```

> But in my opinion, the better way is to use an external NodeJS custom script and run it with a npm script.

Comment: I came across this as well. But having a single command for this action is mandatory. Could you elaborate on how you would use an external NodeJS custom script for this functionality?

Comment: Like that `npm config set myapp:folder mynewfolder && npm run newproject`? What do you want to do exactly? With more info I could elaborate a better solution for you.

Comment: I'm trying to clone a repository into a folder with a custom folder name, after that process is completed I want to open that folder and clone another repository inside the cloned repository folder. This second repository does not require a custom folder name. I'm want to achieve this with a single command. Your sollution works, but requires two seperate commands.

Comment: I think git submodule can be a better solution for you. The second repo will be cloned automatically in the first one when you will clone the first one. So one command. The submodules are the official way to clone a repo inside another.

Comment: Actualy, your original solution does not appear to work either. This seems to be Windows specific. `$npm_package_config_folder` is interpreted as string on Windows.

Comment: Nice idea, but OS specific as well.

Comment: If you do the node script suggestion, you can import package.json. This works on windows: ``const pk = require("./package.json"); const folder = pk.config.folder;``. Just run the git clone as a execSync.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the following page: https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5518 (it's on the answer you linked to)

```
"new_project": "git clone x:/parent_repo $PROJECT & cd $PROJECT & git clone x:/child_repo"
```

Then:

```
npm run --PROJECT new_project_name
```

Comment: That would be `npm run new_project --PROJECT new_project_name` and yields the same results.

Comment: This appears to work on linux, but I don't know how to escape the variable on Windows. `$PROJECT` is interpreted as string on windows machines.