# Variables are not substituted in npm scripts on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I cannot figure out how to use variables in npm scripts on Windows 8, npm 3.10.10 and node 6.11.1.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "echo $npm_package_name"
  }
}
```

and npm start outputs:

```
> echo $npm_package_name

$npm_package_name
```

For some reason, the variable does not substituted. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Articles being read- [https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars) and [variables-in-npm-scripts](http://ianmcnally.me/blog/2016/2/4/variables-in-npm-scripts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables on Windows should be surrounded/escaped with % %. The example above should be:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "echo %npm_package_name%"
  }
}
```

More info could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39868894/1635055).

Comment: There is no cross platform solution to this problem? I develop on Windows and MacOS workstations, test locally, and deploy to Linux servers.

Comment: @Dan doesn't look like there's a built-in way to handle this cross platform, but there [are packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) that can be used to make it work cross platform.