# Cypress: Passing the param into npm script when run by CL

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I tryna pass the param *param1* and *param2* when I run the script by command Line.

Here code in test.cy.js

```
it('Clean data', () => {

    const param1 = process.env.npm_config_param1;
    const param2 = process.env.npm_config_param2;

    before(function () {
        cy.visit('/')

        //Login
        cy.get('#username').type(param1)
        cy.get('#password').type(param2)
        cy.get('#loginBtn').click()
 })
```

I defined script in package.json

```
 "my-script": "npx cypress run --spec \"test.cy.js\" --param1 value1 --param2 value2"
```

I run in CL

```
npm --param1=email111@gmail.com --param2=11111111 run-script my-script
```

I got the error '*error: unknown option: --param1*'

Can I pass the param into npm script of Cypress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-dash is correct way to pass params to inner script, but it needs a space before it.

This answer [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14404223/16997707) shows good example code.

You define script in `package.json`

```js
// no "placeholder" params on the script
"my-script": "npx cypress run --spec \"test.cy.js\""
```

You run in CLI

```js
npm run-script my-script -- --env user=email111@gmail.com,pwd=11111111
```

You use in test

```js
const user = Cypress.env('user');   // email111@gmail.com
const pwd = Cypress.env('pwd');     // 11111111
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define them as environment variable and it's possible in command lines (see [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-4---env)).

In your case, it would be:

```
"my-script": "npx cypress run --spec \"test.cy.js\" --env param1=$value1,param2=$value2"
```

and

```
npm run my-script --value1 email111@gmail.com --value2 11111111
```

You can also refer to this [How to use variables in npm scripts on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793500/how-to-use-variables-in-npm-scripts-on-windows)

Comment: I created environment variable  

`   env : {
        "param1": "test",
        "param2": "122121121",
    }
`


and in test file

`    cy.get('input[autocomplete="username"]').type(`${Cypress.env('param1')}`)

        cy.get('input[autocomplete="current-password"]').type(`${Cypress.env('param2')}`)

 cy.log(`${Cypress.env('param1')}    ${Cypress.env('param2')} `)
`


and run as `npm run my-script --value1 email111@gmail.com --value2 11111111`


but it param1 is test, param2 is 122121121. 

What var should I create in env?

Comment: Then you should be able to get them with `Cypress.env('XXXX')`

Comment: I can not pass my param into it,  I just update comment