# NPM/ Yarn Pass entire command dynamically to a script value as an argument/parameter

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, gulp, yarnpkg

Package.json

```
 {
        custom: "",
        "build:xapp": "webpack ....",
        "test:xapp": "karma ....",
        "build:yapp": "webpack ....",
        "test:yapp": "karma ...."
         ... n number of apps
 }
```

If want to pass the entire command for the custom script as an argument, How can i do that?

something like this

yarn custom -- -"yarn build:xapp, yarn build:yapp, yarn test:xapp"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to run multiple npm scripts that are defined in package.json. I think npm-run-all is what you are looking for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all

Once you install, you can then run `npm-run-all build:xapp build:yapp test:xapp`

If you are looking for passing command line arguments, this has been answered here: [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)