# npm script pass parameters/arguments to node script using yargs

Tags: javascript, npm, yargs

Is it possible to call out to retrieve a key from yargs when using as a npm script argument?

User types in the OSX terminal:

```
npm run scaffold --name=blah
```

which executes in package.json:

```
"scaffold" : "node ./scaffold/index.js -- "
```

This results in

```
const yargs = require('yargs').argv

if (yargs) {
  console.log(yargs);
  console.log(yargs.name);
  process.exit(1)
}
...
result:
{ _: [], '$0': 'scaffold/index.js' }
undefined
```

This only works if I hard code in package.json `"scaffold" : "node scaffold/index.js --name=blah"`, but I need this to be configurable.

As I stated I am using args, as it appears to make it easy to retrieve keys by name ( as opposed to an array ). Open to suggestions.

What am I missing?

**update 11-07-2017**
Related: [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

However, passing in the commandline `1: npm run scaffold name=hello`
 OR `2: npm run scaffold --name=hello` yields:

```
1: { _: [], '$0': 'scaffold/index.js' }
2: { _: [ 'name=hello' ], '$0': 'scaffold/index.js' }
```

Still can't see a way to retrieve the `yargs.name` property. Still undefined.

---

**Update 13-07-2017**

For the time being, I have given up. It just seem impossible. I run the script manually in the terminal.
E.g.

```
node ./scaffold/index.js --name=blah
```

Image below shows executing of a node script directly as opposed to running through npm scripts. I have added https://www.npmjs.com/package/nopt node module to see if it helps ( it doesn't ). `process.argv.name` is still undefined when running through npm scripts.

[image]

---

**Update 18-07-2017**

Added github example: https://github.com/sidouglas/stackoverflow-node-arguments

---

**Update 24-07-2017**

Adding the variables before the start of the command works
`myvar="hello npm run scaffold` as opposed to `npm run scaffold myvar="hello world"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure that it matters where the variables are added on the command line, and if this is of no concern to you, then this works:

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "npm-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Your JS file:

```
//index.js
console.log('myvar', process.env.myvar);
```

And your command line command:

```
myvar="hello world" npm run start
```

So in the end, just prefix your npm script command with your argument list.

Comment: Very interesting. Adding the variable to the start of the command works. At the end, it fails.
Thank you for your answer

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Was just pushing a new branch to your example repo with changes included and github wasn't cooperating.

Answer (score 13):

As of npm@2.0.0, you can use custom arguments when executing scripts. The special option -- is used by getopt to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the -- directly to your script:

`npm run test -- --grep="pattern"`

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

Comment: This answer is not complete. I have been to this page, and read, and re-read, several time. The example you have copy and pasted. In my example, if I console.log your `process.argv`, I *still* do not see the means to retrieve the `name` attribute on process.argv, nor your `grep`argument, in your answer example.

Comment: If you can create a public GitHub repository with your code (package.json, index.js, etc.) I can try and debug it.

Answer (score 5):

For me the following works on Node 10, 12, 14

```
npm run yourscript -- -- --name=bla
```

I do need to use `-- --`

and

```
"yourscript": "node bla.js"
```

Comment: Node 16 (npm 8.3) still has this issue. Only for all these stupid scripts issues I always use yarn rather than npm