# Pass command line variable into npm script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, npm, ecmascript-6

I am trying to pass a command line (specifically not in version control) option to my main `index.js` script, which does some stuff based on a specific S3 bucket.

In my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "bucket_name=${bucket_name:=null} node babel.runtime.js"
},
```

And via command line:

```
npm start -- --bucket_name="test"
```

But `bucket_name` keeps coming back as null, so the var isn't being passed correctly. I assume this is something simple, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

Comment: Set your start script to: `node babel.runtime.js` and do `BUCKET_NAME=test npm start` from your terminal. It should make it available in `process.env.BUCKET_NAME`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You presented two separate ways of assigning variables to the process.

The first one, using an `npm script`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "bucket_name=${bucket_name:=null} node babel.runtime.js"
}
```

This approach sets the `bucket_name` **environment variable** which is accessible from `process.env.bucket_name`.

The second approach, via command line

```
npm start -- --bucket_name="test"
```

This approach sets the `bucket_name` as an **argument** of the running process. This is accessible from `process.argv` array.

Its not that the variable isn't being set for one way or the other, its just about where you're accessing. Each of these sets the `bucket_name` in different places.