# npm command line arguments

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to send command line arguments to npm scripts? This is what I need:

```
"test": "npm run test:build && npm run -s test:run",
"test:build": "rollup -c myArgument",
"test:run": "karma start"
```

and `myArgument` defines the `--environment`, ex. (`rollup -c --environment TEST`).

I am using npm version 3.10.10.

**EDIT**:
I want to know how it is possible when you run the "`npm run test`" NOT the "`npm run test:build`" 
the "`npm test`" runs the `"test:build" and "test:run"`

Comment: `npm run test:build -- --environment test` would pass the additional `environment` parameter to the script being called, not sure how many levels of calling you can do it through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

Comment: @jonrsharpe you answer works when you run the npm test:build. But I need to run with npm test. See the updatd question

Comment: have you tried env variable like $MYARGUMENT

Comment: The duplicate also covers that; that’s what I meant by levels of calling. `ROLLUP_ENV=test npm run test` or something.