# Pass npm script command line arguments to a specific script inside it

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have a scenario where I have to run three npm script to achieve some result in my application. I combined them in one npm script. This is my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "setup": "npm install && npm run some-script && npm install",
    "some-script": "gulp some-other-script"
}
```

what I would like to do is to pass arguments to `setup` script from command line which will be passed further to the `some-script` script.

If I run `npm run script -- --abc=123` the arguments are added at the end of the script but I would like to pass it to specific script (in this case to `npm run some-script`). I also tried to rewrite script definition like this:
`"setup": "npm install && npm run some-script -- --sample=sample&& npm install"` but with no luck.

I'm aware of shell functions (described here: [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script#comment79763335_14404223) and here https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9627) but I need a solution which will work cross-platform.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hello, did you fin how to achieve this, I have same case usage ;)

Comment: Problem seems to come from && part of script

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a work around.

1st goal was to be able to use some script with arguments, and cascade this to the calls of other scripts :

npm run main -- --arg1

`"main": "npm run script1 && npm run script2"`

Problem with this approach is that the cascading would only be done by adding the arg passed to npm run main at the END of the line "npm run script1 && npm run script2". I could find no way to pass it to the 1st element : npm run script1

Here is the work around I found :

1st you need to add in package.json:

```
"config": {
   "arg1": "ARG_VALUE"
},
```

Then in your script you can add it to the call like this :

```
"main": "npm run script_no_arg1 && npm run scrip1 -- --%npm_package_config_arg1% && npm run script2 -- --%npm_package_config_component% && npm run script_no_arg2"
```

Finally, You don't need to call it with any arg : npm run main
But you need to modify ARG_VALUE before launc the script :)

Last thing : in my case I was calling gulp tasks :

```
"cleardown": "rimraf build lib",
"inline-build-templates": "gulp inline-build-templates",
"step1": "npm run cleardown && npm run inline-build-templates -- --%npm_package_config_arg1%",
```

It works you can get the argument into the gulp task that way :

```js
 gulp.task('inline-build-templates', function() {
   let component = process.argv[3];
   component = component.split('--')[1];
   console.log('RUNNING GULP TASK : inline-build-templates for component ' + component);
   // whatever task gulp
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah it seems it is not possible to provide arguments for any other script than the last one in the chain **from the command line**. Your solution is close to what I wanted but I don't want to change some properties in package.json each time I want to execute this command. Thanks anyway