# pass argument from terminal via node to npm scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to do semi automation to create user for my api, so I have this script

```
//getUserInfo.js
const argv = require('yargs-parser')(process.argv.slice(2))

module.exports = (async () => {
    let [ userId ] = argv._ //parsing...

    if(!userId){
        console.log('userId is not defined')
        return
    } 

    userId = userId.split('=')[1] ////parsing, again :(

    console.log(userId) //123
    //proceed with automation steps
    ...
    ...
})()
```

The script is working, so in my `package.json` I have this

```
"scripts": {
  "admin:getUserInfo": "node server/scripts/getUserInfo.js"
}
```

All I need to do is to run `npm run admin:getUserInfo userId=123` and I can get 123 in my terminal.

But the problem is I have to do so many step just to get the userId value.

Comment: Maybe this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script

Comment: @SurajJadhav couldn't find the answer there

Comment: My sincere apologies, I thought you were not able to get `userId` from the passed options. Use `args-parser` instead of `yargs-parser`. [see docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/args-parser) That would save you a few lines of code.