# Dynamic template in webpack react js

Tags: reactjs, templates, dynamic, webpack

I'd like to have multiple builds of application where each build would represent specified `theme`.

`npm build monokai` would generate monokai theme. Project structure would be like this:

```
/themes/default/component.jsx
/themes/monokai/component.jsx
```

Basically it would come down to this `/themes/{themeName}/component.jsx`. Of course there would be whole folder structure in `{themeName}` subdirectory, but every theme would have same folder structure, just different html/css.

Is there a way to achieve this with `webpack`? It doesn't necessarily have to work via `npm build {themeName}`.

Comment: so inject the theme as a global. then dynamically import based off of that theme

Comment: @JohnRuddell I don't think I understand, can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: so, you can access variables via `process.env.npm_config_<somevar>` if you take that variable (aka your theme) and use it to import the theme you should be set. [See this for an example of injecting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19381235/2733506). if you are still having issues put up a codepen or something and ill try and help you with your chunk of code :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell but that would mean that I should import every file via process.env.npm_config_<somevar>? Because that is what I want to avoid and just import { Login } from 'themes/login' which would resolve to 'themes/default/login'

Comment: no, lol you should use the theme defined in a build to set a variable in your application. a theme variable. Then you would import based off that theme

Comment: This is too complicated to just give an answer, if you have a github repo or some place where code is i can help you with it.. but its pretty complicated to just do dynamic importing based off some variable like that