# npm script && and argument from terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have this in my package.json

```
script: {
    "myscript": "babel-node script.js"
}
```

In the terminal I do `npm run myscript my-param`. I'm able to get

`my-param` in script.js, I have this in script.js

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv
const { _ : [ my_param ] } = argv
console.log(my_param)
```

But if I chain my npm script like so

```
script: {
    "myscript": "babel-node script.js && node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.config.js"
}
```

Then I can't pass anything using `npm run myscript.js script.js` from the terminal anymore? I don't see `my-param` in the `console.log`

Comment: Have you tried `npm run myscript -- my-param` ?

Comment: @J.Pichardo yes, it has no different. I searched in other place doesn't look like it has a solution.

Comment: found a solution herehttps://stackoverflow.com/a/25356509/9906576