# How to create a new API Gateway http endpoint from the terminal in one command

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-api-gateway

I'd like to be able to deploy new endpoints for my api from the command line, ideally with a single npm script.

The hangup is that you first have to use `create-resource` supplying a parent id, and then `put-method` supplying the id returned from `create-resource`.

This carves up deploying into a series of small steps that I can't string together, because I need these unique id's.

Any way around this? I'm using npm scripts exclusively so far with getting lambdas up, which has been fairly pleasant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `package.json` a script can point to a javascript file. The file in turn could contain a more robust script.

```
"scripts": {
  "createEndpoint": "node ./myscript.js"
}
```

To do it all in one command/script you might want to look at how to process arguments this question/answer talks about how it works https://stackoverflow.com/a/14404223/10555693. Additionally, NodeJS docs for argv [NodeJS: process.argv](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_argv)

The more robust script could make use of the [JS AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html), take in arguments, and create the resource, method, and deployment.

Some specific method references you might find useful:

- [Create Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#createResource-property)
- [Put Method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#putMethod-property)

Example (Just a start):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

async function createEndPoint() {
  const apiGateway = new AWS.APIGateway();

  const resourceParams = {
    parentId: '',
    pathPart: '',
    restApiId: '',
  };

  const newResource = await apiGateway.createResource(resourceParams).promise();

  const methodParams = {
    resourceId: newResource.id,
    . /* other params */
    .
    .
  };

  const newMethod = await apiGateway.putMethod(methodParams);
}

createEndPoint();
```

Comment: Lovin' the await/async stuff here : ) Thanks for the advice. Was trying to keep it all in the npm scripts, but perhaps that's wishful thinking. I have a deploy script like this for my static site. Maybe I'll need one for lambdas running backend services as well.