# Minimist js library not returning key-value pair

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, minimist

This is the code:

```
var minimist = require('minimist')
const args = minimist(process.argv.slice(2))
console.log(args)
```

In the terminal, I type: `npm start -a abc -b bbc`

```
$ npm start -a abc -b bbc
{ _: [ 'abc', 'bbc' ] }
```

**This is what I expected:**

```
{ _: [], a: 'abc', b: 'bbc' }
```

This might sound silly, but please help me get out of this...

Comment: `'splice' !== 'slice'`

Comment: oh sorry, that was a typo

Comment: but the result is still the same

Comment: See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start, you need `--`.

Comment: i tried with `--` it still doesn't work. and minimist doc allowed every type of arg

Comment: do you have a `start` script? if not, does it work with `node server.js -a abc -b bbc` ?

Comment: oh yeah, I see it has a start script

Comment: it does not work with node server.js -a abc -b bbc

Comment: but it works with just this commad `server` [I installed the module golbally]

Answer (score 1):

**npm 2 and newer**

Use `--` prefix to pass `args` to `npm run` since npm 2 (2014). The syntax is as follows:

```
$ npm run <command> [-- <args>]
```

Your command should look like this:

```
$ npm start -- -a abc -b bbc
{ _: [], a: 'abc', b: 'bbc' }
```

Note the `--` separator, used to separate the params passed to npm command itself, and the params passed to your script.

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)