# Pass params to Angular 6 app through npm commands

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to pass a param for --configuration (environments) to angular application from package json command:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng build"   ???
},
```

i need to reflect this on package.json because te current situation i cannot pass anything just using npm build  --- > (final command i want is ng build --configuration=CERT).

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the environment.ts to environment.CERT.ts (if configuration = CERT).
There you can add all the predefined value there, for example

```
export const environment = {
    name: 'CERT';
};
```

Then you can import it in your application, anywhere

`import { environment } from 'environment'`

and use it as `environment.name`

Hope this help