# How override nodejs config when it run from npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-config

[Here](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Command-Line-Overrides) is documentation about node config:

```
node myapp.js --NODE_CONFIG='{"Customer":{"dbConfig":{"host":"customerdb.prod"}}}'
```

BUt what if I run `npm` script? In this case all parameters will passed into `npm` not `nodejs`, am I wrong? How to pass `--NODE_CONFIG` from command line?

**P.S.** set up `NODE_CONFIG` as environment variable is not a solution in my case.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script

Answer (score 0):

In order to inject args into an inner npm command, you need to use a `--` delimiter.

package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "myscript": "node myapp.js"
}
```

And run this command to inject the NODE_CONFIG

```
npm run myscript -- --NODE_CONFIG='{"Customer":{"dbConfig":{"host":"customerdb.prod"}}}'
```