# Do we can specify max instances in terminal?

Tags: protractor

Can we specify max instances in the terminal?

**Protractor.conf.js file**

```
module.exports = {
    allScriptsTimeout: process.env.TIMEOUT || 45000,
    directConnect: true,
    baseUrl: process.env.TEST_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:8085/',
    framework: 'mocha',
    getPageTimeout: 10000,
    mochaOpts: {
        reporter: 'test/mochaReporter.js',
        timeout: 60000,
    },
    onPrepare: () => {
        global.chai = chai;
        global.expect = chai.expect;
        chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    },
};
```

for example: TEST_BASE_URL=https://www.example.com/ TIMEOUT=20000 npm run e2e

TIMEOUT === timeout

TEST_BASE_URL === base URL

Comment: I don't understand what you need

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14404223/10836734) may be off use to you