# How to pass command line arguments values to config file in protractor using node.js

Tags: node.js, protractor

I am trying to get command line argument values using NPM package "**yargs**" instead of retrieving the values from config.ts file.

**Example:** 
My config.ts file looks like

```
export const config: Config = {  
 username: process.argv[3],                                                                     
  password: process.argv[4]                       
}
```

And in my package.json file I already defined my scripts for "**test**": "./node_modules/.bin/protractor typeScript/config/config.js",

In my testcase i am retrieving values as "config.username" & "config.password"

So when i execute npm test --username1 --password1 , my testcase which is executing is picking values from config.ts file and not the values which i passed "username1" and "password1" from command line. 
Can someone please help me in picking the values from command line and not from the config.ts file.

Thanks in advance.. !!!

Comment: Can you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1.

For protractor side check out [this page](https://moduscreate.com/blog/protractor_parameters_adding_flexibility_automation_tests/)

Per its content, having this in your `conf.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  params: {
    login: {
      email: 'default',
      password: 'default'
    }
  },
    //  * other config options *
}
```

you can pass any parameter to it in CMD as follows:

```
protractor --baseUrl='http://some.server.com' conf.js --parameters.login.email=example@gmail.com 
--parameters.login.password=foobar
```

so you end up having this in your specs:

```
describe('describe some test', function() {
  it('describe some step', function() {
    browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
    $('.email').sendKeys(browser.params.login.email);
    $('.password').sendKeys(browser.params.login.password);
  });
});
```

BUT! These variables are not available in your config and only in specs.

## 2.

If you need variables to be reused in config (conditional suites etc) The way I'm doing this is following

Lets assume you have a command to start your tests

```
protractor config.js --baseUrl="www.example.com"
```

you can declare environment variables BEFORE that command like so

```
INFO=something PARAM=parameter protractor config.js --baseUrl="www.example.com"
```

And then in your protractor config you can refer to those variables by typing

```
console.log(process.env.INFO);
console.log(process.env.PARAM);
```

Note that you don't even need additional packages for this approach

Comment: I used solution1 and did some changes along with what is suggested like in config.ts file i added process.argv[3] for baseUrl and when i run the test as "./node_modules/.bin/protractor typeScript/config/config.js --http://www.google.com" , script is taking value along with -- and if i dont give -- like "./node_modules/.bin/protractor typeScript/config/config.js http://www.google.com" and run the test then it is throwing error :Error: more than one config file specified. Can you please help me if you know how can i resolve this.

Comment: `.replace("--","")`?

Comment: Thanks..!! It resolved my issue , but by any chance do you any have idea on how i can pass a value with double quotes like "username" from command line.

Comment: probably you just need to escape it `"\"your value\""`

Comment: I tried that also but it is taking value as \\@Test\\ when I passed it as  -\"@Test\"