# mode in project building in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

i have two `env` files in my vue js project

```
- .env.development
- .env.production
```

i want to build the project with command `npm run build --mode development` or `npm run build --mode production` for build based on my env files based on vue docs.

and i get this error

```
Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/var/www/html/projectname/production' in '/var/www/html/projectname'
```

what is the solution??

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script) ; `npm run build -- --mode development`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

Comment: @birdspider id dont think so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file setup seem correct, it looks like you need to change your command from this:

```
npm run build --mode production
```

to this

```
npm run build -- --mode production
```

According to this github thread: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1528#issuecomment-395970443

Copying the comment there:

> "In other words: all arguments before -- are interpreted as arguments for npm itself, not the script you are running."

---

Alternatively, if you don't use the npm script shortcut, you can use `vue-cli-service` directly:

```
vue-cli-service build --mode production
```