# CodeceptJS - pass --grep and --profile arguments via npm

Tags: node.js, npm, codeceptjs

I want to pass mutilple CLI arguments through npm to codeceptJS.

E.g. we use tags for device specific tests and we have different test environments. I want to do:

```
"e2e": "codeceptjs run --steps -c path/to/config.js --grep --profile"
```

So I could pass in:

```
npm run e2e @iPhoneX env=qa
```

I've tried multiple combinations but can't get it to work with both grep and profile. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't pass arguments via npm scripts like that, there's no way to interpolate what you're passing with `npm run` within the value of `e2e`. Try something like `npm run e2e -- --grep @iPhoneX --profile env=qa`.

Comment: Out scripts are setup to run in this configuration. running npm run e2e will run as expected, it's the grep and profille together that's the issue.

Comment: `--grep` won't ever work, because you always pass the arguments at the end, to `--profile`. NPM tells you this; when you run `npm run e2e @iPhoneX env=qa` it shows that it's actually running `codeceptjs run --step -c path/to/config.js --grep --profile "@iPhoneX" "env=qa"`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes you're right, so is there no way to run both of these together so it does: `--grep "@iPhoneX" --profile  "env=qa"`

Comment: No; again, *"there's no way to interpolate what you're passing"*, they all go at the end. You could do it via env vars, but you'd have to change how you're calling it - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30906986/3001761.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, I'll look into env vars. I misunderstood your first comment.