# WebdriverIO how to specify the test to run from npm command

Tags: npm, webdriver-io

I am using WebdriverIO.

I start my tests from the command line using 'npm test', which triggers the command: wdio wdio.conf.js as specified in my package.json here:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "wdio wdio.conf.js"
  },
```

What I want to do is specify the actual test to run like this:

wdio wdio.conf.js --spec ./test/specs/e2e/login.js

My question is, how do I pass in the testcase from the npm command, i.e. how can I pass this --spec ./test/specs/e2e/login.js from the npm command into the wdio command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
npm run test -- --spec ./test/specs/e2e/login.js
```

Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14404223/3879644

Comment: The above works but what if you want to run a specific feature?