# Pass parameter to npm run "my command" and use that parameter in my functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

Consider app.js

```
const { doCoolStuff } = require("./api/myApi");
// grab param from command line into "myParam"


doCoolStuff(myParam);

... // more code
```

And **Package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "-------",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "send": "node app.js"
  },
  
  ... 
}
```

How can we pass parameter to `app.js` when running `npm run send` ?

Something like `npm run send myEmail@myDomain.com`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script I think your question is answered here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
const params = process.argv.slice(2)
```

Now this param variable has all the parameters passed with the npm run command.

```
npm run send myEmail@domain.com

params[0] // this will provide you with the value myEmail@domain.com
```

Answer (score 23):

Npm will parse any argument you pass to the script unless it's passed after -- followed by a space. After npm parses them, they'll be available under npm_config_ in the environment variables.

```
{
      "scripts": {
        "send": "echo \"send email to $npm_config_name @ $npm_config_mail "
      }
    }
```

Then run

```
npm run send --mail=xyz.com --name=sample
```

output: `send email to sample@xyz.com`

Comment: I think you forgot an \" at the end and the command name in your example should be `send` instead of `demo`. So: `npm run send --mail=xyz.com --name=sample`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) to access the arguments in your script.

As for how to specify your arguments, see: [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)