# Run a custom function with imports and arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, npm-scripts

In a `npm` project I want to call a custom function with arguments, or better, provide it as a script in the `package.json` in a manner like: `npm run custom-function "Hello, World"`.

At the moment I have a a file `src/myFunction.ts`:

```js
import * as extLib from 'libFromNodeModules'; // we need npm to resolve this dependency

export const runFunction = function (arg: string) {
  console.log(extLib.process(arg));
};
```

The closest thing I've managed to call this function is:

```json
{
  ...
  scripts: {
        "custom-function": "ts-node -e 'require(\"./src/myFunction.ts\").runFunction()'",
  }
  ...
}
```

This does a tad more than just `ts-node src/myFunction.ts`, but still doesn't allow me to pass arguments and is probably not the right approach anyway. How do I have to set this up correctly?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script

Comment: @danh In that case I would need to know how the `script.js` there looks like that it accepts arguments when called in that manner. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run foo.js, passing "bar"...

```
"scripts": {
  "custom": "node foo.js bar"
}
```

> npm run custom

`process.argv` is set to the command line...

```
// foo.js
console.log(process.argv) // prints ['path/node', 'path/foo.js', 'bar']
```