# Package.json variable not being picked up

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following functionality that locally loads some products out of stock depending on the command run in the terminal:

```
const updates = process.env.option === "oos" ? oosUpdates : insUpdates
log.info("updates: ", JSON.stringify(updates))
const result = await loadUpdateVariants(cache, updates as UpdateType[])
```

In my package.json I have:

```
"update:oos": "ts-node src/loaders/mock/update-variants.ts --option oos",
"update:ins": "ts-node src/loaders/mock/update-variants.ts --option ins"
```

however when I run `yarn update:oos` I am getting the `instock` products meaning that this `process.env.option === "oos"` is not working out correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

Comment: Doesn't `--option` go on `process.argv` and not `process.env`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`process.env` gives you access to environment variables. If you want to use environment variables, you can set them like this:

```json
"update:oos": "OPTION=oos ts-node src/loaders/mock/update-variants.ts",
"update:ins": "OPTION=ins ts-node src/loaders/mock/update-variants.ts"
```

This is the "vanilla" (without any extra dependencies) approach - but may encounter issues on Windows. If you want your command to work well cross-platform, you might consider using [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

Comment: Don't set environment variables like that, it isn't supported properly cross platform. Use `cross-env` instead.

Comment: Good point, thanks, I have added in a note to the answer about that.