# How to pass command line arguments to yarn script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, package.json

I want to use command line argument and use this value to replace in url in yarn script.
My script looks like this -

```
"demo:req": "curl -s -D - -o /dev/null https://test.com/demo?request=true&type=${0} | grep -i '^location: ' | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/https/http/' | sed 's/test.com/localhost:3012/'",
```

So when I run

```
yarn demo:req type1
```

it should replace the ${0} with type1 before triggering the curl command. But this is not working.

I tried to use ${TYPE} in url and run the command as

```
yarn demo:req TYPE=type1
```

but still no luck.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script . You may be able to do something like `TYPE=type1 yarn demo:req` to run the command, and then the parameter $TYPE in your script definition in package.json. This should work in *nix environments, but it may not work in Command Prompt on Windows.