# Does double dash work differently for npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I was looking into understanding how -- works recently when I've seen it used on command lines and I learned that it separates a command and it's options from other arguments, so that the command knows not to expect any further options after the -- e.g.

```
 grep -- --hello data.txt
```

however I was reading some npm articles and I came across this command in a package.json file:

```
"lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
```

What I'm confused about here is that the --fix option is being passed after the double dashes, isn't this against how the -- syntax is meant to work?

Comment: look at your lint script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

Comment: Ah thanks, so it is a combination of an option that is also being passed as an argument, I hadn't seen it that way, thanks.