# How do I pass more variables to my npm script

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, typeorm

I am using typeorm with nextjs. Unfortunately to use manual migrations it seems to be incredibly difficult to get working. Firstly I have the following npm script:

```
"typeorm": "ts-node -P cli-tsconfig.json -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config ./config/typeorm.config.ts"
```

This allows me to run:

```
npm run typeorm migration:run
```

and it works. However, if I want to create a migration I run:

```
npm run typeorm migration:create -n mymigration
```

And it fails with the error:

> > ts-node -P cli-tsconfig.json -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config ./config/typeorm.config.ts
> > "migration:create" "mymigration"
>
> Missing baseUrl in compilerOptions. tsconfig-paths will be skipped
> bin.js migration:create
>
> Creates a new migration file.
>
> Options:   -h, --help        Show help
> [boolean]   -c, --connection  Name of the connection on which run a
> query.
> [default: "default"]   -n, --name        Name of the migration class.
> [required]   -d, --dir         Directory where migration should be
> created.   -f, --config      Name of the file with connection
> configuration.
> [default: "ormconfig"]   -o, --outputJs    Generate a migration file on
> Javascript instead of
> Typescript                        [boolean] [default: false]   -v, --version     Show version number
> [boolean]
>
> Missing required argument: n npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1

Clearly it's not picking up the parameter but I have no idea how to get around this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like described in [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script), you need to separate additional arguments from the npm command with `--`

`npm run typeorm -- migration:create -n mymigration`