# How to pass file file path as arguement to the script?

Tags: node.js, npm, path, require, package.json

I want to send the data from

package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node list.js",
}
```

list.js:

```
const serviceAccount = require(path);
```

when I execute command `npm start ./style.json` I wanted to pass the path to to `path` variable in list.js

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to use [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#processargv), the third item is `./style.json`. inside `list.js` use this:

```
const path = process.argv[2]
const serviceAccount = require(path);
console.log(serviceAccount)
```

Comment: what are the changes I should do in **package.json**:`scripts": {
    "start": "node list.js",`

Comment: No changes required,  just run the same package.json with this command: `npm start ./style.json`