# How to pass command line aruguement to npm script with process.argv?

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments, package.json, argv

I have package.json like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node list_users.js",
}
```

and list.js file

```
    const process = require('process');
var args = process.argv;
```

when I run npm start  I want to pass this  to pass to JS file, How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Execution of npm scripts follows this syntax: `npm run <command> [-- <args>]`.

In your case, this is: `npm run start --first-argument first` or using the shorthand for the start script `npm start --first-argument first`. Mind that the part in brackets is optional.

This is the according [PR](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5518) from 2014 which enhanced npm to enable this. Also, this question already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass through npm script then just add the values as arguments.
Example:

Modify your `list_users.js`

```
var args = process.argv;
console.log(args.slice(2));
```

Run command `npm start user1 user2 user3`

The command prints:-

```
> node list_users.js "user1" "user2" "user3"

[ 'user1', 'user2', 'user3' ]
```