# How to execute jest tests in a particular folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, jestjs

I want the script command below to have something like  where it should run tests in that folder name

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --testPathPattern==tests/<folder-name> --maxWorkers=2"
  },
```

to run tests in a particular folder.

This command is executed in a bash file `run-tests.sh` as shown below

```
#!/bin/bash
npm run test
```

is it possible to have something like

```
#!/bin/bash
npm run test <folder-name>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

Answer (score 1):

According to the jest documentation you should be able to do this:

```
npm run test -- --testPathPattern==tests/<folder-name>
```

source:
https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#using-with-npm-scripts

Alternatively something like this in your bash script should do the trick as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
pushd <directory here> # Basically cd into that directory
npm run test
popd # cd back into where we came from when we ran pushd
```

I think this will do what you are asking.