# Using command line arguments in npm run script

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I am trying to change the {variable} part in my custom-defined npm run deploy script

```
"scripts":{
      "deploy": "npm run build && scp -r ./public example@192.200.0.11:/home/{DIRECTORY}/index.js",
}
```

I want to run it like `npm run deploy --DIRECTORY:project99`

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to npm run as Environment variable. See [Npm Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config)

```
 "scripts": {
    "deploy": "npm run build && scp -r ./public example@192.200.0.11:/home/${NPM_CONFIG_DIRECTORY}/index.js"
    },
```

This should work

```
npm run deploy --DIRECTORY=project99
```