# How do I pass parameters to an NPM script that uses nodenv?

Tags: parameter-passing, package.json, npm-run, yargs, nodenv

I have a NodeJS app that uses the NPM package [node-env-run](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-env-run) (i.e. to load environment variables from `.env` file). The `package.json`, I have a script that looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
     "run-jobs": "nodenv tests/run-jobs.js"
}
```

Sometimes when I run `npm run run-jobs`, I don't want to run **all** jobs, but only one or a few. I am looking for a way to pass the names of those jobs to the script so that I can filter for them in the script by looking at `process.argv`

I have tried following answers on Stackoverflow ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)) and elsewhere, but I cannot get this to work. For example, I have tried:

- `npm run run-jobs myjob1 myjob2`
- `npm run run-jobs -- myjob1 myjob2`
- `npm run run-jobs --myjob1 --myjob2`
  ...

All of these are either not being picked up in `argv` or resulting in errors from `nodenv`.

Is there a way to do this, and if so what is the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bunch of trial and error and digging into the `node-env-run.js` code, I've got it.

The syntax to get this working is

`npm run run-jobs -- -- myjob1 myjob2`