# How to use environment variable in npm script on Windows

Tags: npm-scripts

###### The problem

Ideally, I need to use a variable passed via terminal in some npm scripts.
For example, with the command `set TOKEN=blabla&& npm run staging`, where the scripts look like the following:

```
"staging": "run-s build:steps:* && run-s langcheck",
"build:steps:env": "npx dotenv-vault pull .env --dotenvMe=$TOKEN",
```

I want the $TOKEN to be replaced by the value passed in the terminal.

However, this did not work. And trying to troubleshoot, I ended up with a very minimal reproduction that I documented below.

### Minimal Reproduction

Need to pass an environment variable to npm script inside package.json.

```
...
"scripts": {
    "check": "echo $SECRET",
}
...
```

Using the following command on Windows

```
set SECRET=hello&& npm run check
```

###### Actual Output vs Expected Output

The output shows $SECRET instead of the "hello" that is intended

```
> echo $SECRET

$SECRET
```

How can I "receive" the passed variable inside the npm script?

###### What I tried

I have tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356509/1914985) from another StackOverflow question, but does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: I find the wording of the quesion unclear: If I'm not mistaken, the problem is not how to **pass** an environment variable, but how to actually **use** such an environment variable inside npm. If I'm right, the tag _npm-scripts_ should be sufficient and I suggest to remove the other tags.

Comment: Whats this got to do with Powershell?

Comment: I have updated the tags. Removed the unrelated ones and rephrased the question.

Comment: SET MY_ENV_VAR=BLA works on my Windows 10, I can get "BLA" value in runtime (python/vscode environment)