# Running react native on different port package.json setup issues

Tags: react-native

I have a package.json that has a run script. I like to know is there a way I can run a script with variable command entered from the terminal

example:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-native start --port={port from terminal} && npm run ios --port={port from terminal}"
  }
}
```

Then in terminal yarn run dev --port=7000

Answer (score 1):

Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script) you can do this by adding `--` before your `[-- <args>]`

Example:

```bash
npm run server -- --port=1337
```