# Angular tests does not run in headless chrome mode

Tags: angular, unit-testing, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to build aws code pipeline for my angular project. For this, the test cases need to run silently on code build stage.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

**karma.conf.js**

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
        require('karma-jasmine'),
        require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
        require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
        require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
        require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
        clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
        dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/piplelinetest'),
        reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
        fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'ChromeHeadless', 'ChromeHeadlessCI'],
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
    customLaunchers: {
        ChromeHeadlessCI: {
            base: 'ChromeHeadless',
            flags: ['--no-sandbox', '–disable-setuid-sandbox', '–disable-gpu']
        }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
});
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "pipeline",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
"test": "ng test"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.12.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.8",
"@angular/cli": "~15.2.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
"@types/node": "^15.2.8",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
"jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
"typescript": "~4.9.4"
}
}
```

Then I'm trying to run the tests with the command:

```
 npm run test pipeline --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI
```

This runs the tests but opens the browser. May be because of this, the code build stage is stuck and not finishing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following command?

```
npm run test -- --project pipeline --watch false --progress false --browsers ChromeHeadlessCI
```

Looking at the documentation, there seems to be no `no-watch` and `no-progress`: https://angular.io/cli/test.

Also, we need `-- --` most likely because of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65530483/7365461.