# Options are not passed to NestJS command

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, nest-commander

Following the [nestjs-commander docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/nest-commander) I have this command:

```
import { Command, CommandRunner, Option } from 'nest-commander';

@Command({
  name: 'my-command',
})
export class MyCommand extends CommandRunner {
  async run(inputs: string[], options: Record<string, any>): Promise<void> {
    console.log(options); // This is an empty object
  }

  @Option({
    flags: '-l, --limit <limit>',
    description: 'Limit option',
  })
  parseLimit(val: string) {
    return Number(val);
  }
}
```

And this is my main-cli.ts file:

```
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import { CommandFactory } from "nest-commander";

async function bootstrap() {
  await CommandFactory.run(AppModule, ["log"]);
}

bootstrap();
```

And I have added `"console:dev": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main-cli.ts"` to my package.json but when I run the command with `npm run console:dev my-command --limit=10` the command runs normally but I don't get the `limit` value in the `run` method.

Any idea why the options are not passed to the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but it was a problem with how the npm works.

Try this:

```bash
npm run console:dev my-command -- --limit=10
```

Reference

- [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)