How to Properly Pass Command-Line Options for Node Test Scripts in GitHub Actions?
I'm working on a GitHub Actions workflow that executes tests using an npm script defined in my package.json. However, I've noticed that some options seem to be ignored when passed in this context. For instance, I need to pass --test-shard=${{ matrix.shard }}/6 to my script, but since the npm command structure requires options to be specified before the path to the test files, it ends up being ignored.
$ node -h
Usage: node [options] script.js [arguments]

Here’s an example of my npm script:
"scripts": {
  "test-hello": "node --test 'test/**/*.test.js'"
}

When I run it like this in my github action workflow:
- run: xvfb-run npm run test-hello -- --test-shard=${{ matrix.shard }}/4

The argument --test-shard=${{ matrix.shard }}/4 is added after the file path and is ignored.
How can I set up my workflow to accept these options correctly, and how can I ensure they are processed as intended during execution? Any insights or best practices for managing command-line arguments in GitHub Actions would be greatly appreciated!

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25356509/7670262. You may use an env var to configure this same as the PORT example in that SO thread. Place it according to your use case. Pass on the shard value or the complete arg whatever you need. For example, configure it like this node --test --test-shard="$SHARD_INDEX/4" 'test/**/*.test.js' and then invoke it after setting SHARD_INDEX env var (via env context or from the CLI).

In package.json:
"scripts": {
  "test-hello": "node --test $TEST_SHARD 'test/**/*.test.js'"
}

In GitHub Actions:
run: |
  export TEST_SHARD="--test-shard=${{ matrix.shard }}/4"
  xvfb-run npm run test-hello 

This setup works because:
The environment variable TEST_SHARD is set in the shell before npm is called.
When npm runs the script, it spawns a new shell process to execute the command.
This new shell inherits the environment variables from the parent shell, including TEST_SHARD.
