# Make a script which accept command-line arguments

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments

What is the correct syntax for running a Node.js script with command-line arguments on Linux or Mac?

To run the script with no arguments, I would simply use the command `node stuff.js`, but in this case, I'd like to run a script called `stuff.js` with the arguments `"blah", "hee", "woohoo!"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass command line arguments to node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js)

Comment: Can the same be used if i am starting my script as npm start?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

See http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv

In summary you'll run it like

`node stuff.js blah hee "whoohoo!"`

Then your arguments are available in `process.argv`

Comment: Does this apply to Windows as well as Mac/Linux/Unix?

Comment: Yep, that's standard on all platforms

Comment: Also, is the quote on the string "whoohoo" necessary (or is it a typo)?

Comment: In *nix the exclamation mark is used for event designators in the shell, so it's good practice to quote or escape arguments where you want the literal character '!'. (Note that your program won't get the quotes as part of the string in the 5th entry of argv, it'll just be whoohoo!)

Comment: @hexist What if you had an argument called `ah hah` and needed to add that to the list of parameters? Would you also have to quote it like you did for `woohoo!` above so that the invocation is `node stuff.js blah hee "whoohoo!" "ah hah"`? The argv documentation doesn't get into details about vars with spaces, which is important because it appears to delimit on spaces.

Comment: @Wimateeka Short answer: yes you need quotes if you have spaces. Long answer: That's not going to be documented in node because that's a os/shell thing, just as is the "whoohoo!" thing. Whatever invokes the node process is responsible for delimiting the arguments, not node. However the defacto standard used by shells and such is to require quotes when passing in arguments that have spaces or certain special characters, so yes, use quotes.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to do more sophisticated stuff, the following modules are really helpful:

- [yargs](https://github.com/bcoe/yargs) by Benjamin Coe
- [commander](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js) by TJ Holowaychuk
- [vorpal](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) by David Caccavella
- [nopt](https://github.com/isaacs/nopt) by Isaac Schlueter

And for fun

- [cli-table](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cli-table) by Guillermo Rauch
- [node-multimeter](https://github.com/substack/node-multimeter) by substack
- [chalk](https://github.com/chalk/chalk) by Sindre Sorhus

Answer (score 4):

[Nomnom](https://github.com/harthur/nomnom) is another possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

This simple node module is also helpfull: [command-line-args](https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-args)

It allows to define a simple definition:

```
const optionDefinitions = [
  { name: 'verbose', alias: 'v', type: Boolean },
  { name: 'src', type: String, multiple: true, defaultOption: true },
  { name: 'timeout', alias: 't', type: Number }  
]
```

It validates your options and allows you to access them in a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

The arguments are stored in

**process.argv**
and to pass the arguments in command line please check below example:

ex. in this example below i have used commander NPM Module.
**var args = require('commander')**

**Options** with commander are defined with the **.option()** method. 
The example below parses args and options from **process.argv**, leaving remaining args as the program.args array which were not consumed by options.
here **process.argv** is An array containing the command line arguments. The first element will be 'node', the second element will be the name of the JavaScript file. The next elements will be any additional command line arguments
after executing.

```
function list(val) {
    return val.split(',');
}
args.version('0.11.2')
    .option('-t, --tag [value]', 'tags to ignore', list, undefined)
    .parse(process.argv);
```

here to take input from command-line, we have to execute .js file with -t and after that arguments separated by comma(,)incase of multiple arguments
**ex. : node example.js -t tagname** 
here i have used list to process multiple command line arguments ,so that we can pass multiple command line arguments 
**ex. node example.js -t tagname1, tagname2**
so after this , all input passed as command line arguments will be available in array named args, so can use this array for your purpose 
and 
you can read more about it from here:-

> https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv

or you can make use of the following modules :

1. **commander**:-

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander

2. **yargs** :-

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs

3. **vorpal** :-

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/vorpal

Comment: The question is about how to pass the arguments to the node script, not how to process them in the script.