# Node JS return undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using a basic node.js introduction script, and i am passing in a argument in the command line.
i want this argument to be passed back to the client after it has run. I can pass back anything that is pure text or values, but i can't pass back a variable containing the same information.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>get test</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Get Test</h1>
  <div id="test"></div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({url: 'http://localhost',dataType: "jsonp",jsonpCallback: "_testcb",cache: false,timeout: 5000,success: function(data) {
          $("#test").append(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
        }
      });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my server code:

```
var http = require('http');
var arr = new Array();
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);

  // print process.argv
  process.argv.forEach(function(val, index, array) {
    console.log(index + ': ' + val);
    arr[index] = val;
    res.write("Size" + val);
    res.end('_testcb(\'{"Size: \' + val + \'"}\')');
  });


  console.log(arr[2]);
}).listen(80);
```

So my question is, how do i pass back objects/ variables/ arrays rather than static text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to send data to the client, you need to serialize the data into JSON in order send the values to the client.

For example, to send **all** of the arguments to the client, you can simply change the method to:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);

  res.write("_testcb(" + JSON.stringify(process.argv) + ")");
}).listen(80);
```

Which will make `data` (on the client) an array of all the arguments to the process.

If you want to pass a different type of object, create the variable the way that you want it, and again, use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert the data to text which can then be sent.  For example:

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);

  // create an empty object
  var data = {};

  // add a size attribute
  data["Size"] = process.argv[1];

  res.write("_testcb(" + JSON.stringify(data) + ")");
}).listen(80);
```

The key to all of this, is the [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method - it allows you to convert your variables into JSON which the client then parses to be data.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, and thanks for the indepth explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass text back and forth, but you can pass text in JSON format and parse it on the client/server.

**EDIT**

Just in case I misinterpreted this question and you are looking to get the command line arguments that your nodejs process was started with, take a look at this thread:

[How do I pass command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js)

The arguments are stored in `process.argv`

Comment: Okay thanks, yeah i knew about the `process.argv`, and was trying to get the 3rd entry into the array to be returned back to the client.

Comment: You're ending the response **inside** the for loop.