# Node.js : how to pass parameter's value from terminal to JS script

Tags: node.js, svg

**Given a `jsdom` based `svgcreator.node.js` script file :**

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
jsdom.env(
  "<html><body></body></html>",        // CREATE DOM HOOK
  [ 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js',    // JS DEPENDENCIES online ...
  'js/d3.v3.min.js' ],                 // ... & offline
// D3JS CODE * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
  function (err, window) {
    var svg = window.d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100);
    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("id", "rect1")
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("width", 80)
        .attr("height", 80)
        .style("fill", "green");
    // END svg design

  //PRINTING OUT SELECTION
    console.log(window.d3.select("body").html());
 }
// END (D3JS) * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
);
```

**Given I use NodeJS terminal command to run it and generate a `output.svg` file :**

```
node svgcreator.node.js > output.svg  # nodeJS + script command
```

**How to pass a parameter's value from the terminal to NodeJS ?**

---

Dependencies for tests:

- [**svgcreator.node.js github repository**](https://github.com/hugolpz/svgcreator.node.js):  `git clone 'git@github.com:hugolpz/svgcreator.node.js.git'`
- jsdom required, use : `sudo npm install -g jsdom` (global).

---

**Solution used (@Matt_Harrison):** we rely on `process.env.myVar`

**`svgcreator.node.js` JS code :**

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
jsdom.env(
  "<html><body></body></html>",        // CREATE DOM HOOK:
  [ 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js',    // JS DEPENDENCIES online ...
  'js/d3.v3.min.js' ],                 // ... & offline
// D3JS CODE * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
  function (err, window) {

    var color = process.env.COLOR;     // <<################# IMPORTANT !!
    var svg = window.d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100);
    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("id", "rect1")
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", 10)
        .attr("width", 80)
        .attr("height", 80)
        .style("fill", color);         // <<################# IMPORTANT !!
    // END svg design

  //PRINTING OUT SELECTION
    console.log(window.d3.select("body").html());
 }
// END (D3JS) * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
);
```

**Terminal NodeJS command :**

```
COLOR=#66AAFF node svgcreator.node.js > out.svg   # <<############# IMPORTANT !! setting the value.
```

+1 @Matt_Harrison answer and the question appreciated !

Comment: I am not pretty sure if you are looking for this only but ..you can use process.argv for passing parameter from terminal to browser

Comment: I want to pass parameters from terminal to my script `jsdom.node.js`, which runs in **nodejs JS engine**.

Comment: Sorry! i am also new to node.js but i am preety sure, you can pass parameter from terminal to js file using process.argv array. for ex. node test.js 2 on terminal and in js file you can get it like console.log(process.argv[2]). hope it helps

Comment: Your good will is welcome, we learn by trying~

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your terminal, you can use [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable):

```
$ COLOR=#FFFFFF node jsdom.node.js
```

In your JS, do:

```
var color = process.env.COLOR;
```

---

Or you could add extra arguments to the command:

```
$ node jsdom.node.js '#FFFFFF'
```

and in your JS :

```
var color = process.argv[2];
```

---

If you want to use a library; I would advise looking into the [Minimist](https://github.com/substack/minimist) library, or [Commander](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js) for a more fully-featured solution.

Comment: When you say `This will then be available` you means `within the js / d3js script` right? (just checking).

Comment: Coming (dinner was here). I will add to my JS some `var color = process.env.COLOR;`, and run that.

Comment: n⁰1 works ! I edited your answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok, validated ! The answer is fully working, and have been improved to be plain clear.

Comment: Is there something like `node svgcreator.node.js COLOR='#FFFFFF' > out.svg` together with `var color = process.argv[COLOR];` ? I just tried but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Done. Minimist is nice indeed. The Nodejs file header get `var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));` you then define it as `var color = argv.COLOR;` and last, need to call the variable such `style("fill", color);`. So I can now use something node `svgcreator.node.js --COLOR=#66AAFF > out.svg`