# How to create custom cli commands for own npm package

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a simple package called for example: `mypkg`

I have registered this package in npm, so I can install it globally:

```
$ npm install -g mypkg
```

My question is how can I bind command options for my package, similar to:

```
$ mypkg build
$ mypkg serve --remote-access
$ mypkg deploy
$ mypkg test
```

Etc.. Exists documentation for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-npm-seed?__hstc=72727564.928d31b2778a3092dba2e38906a8821d.1422973190884.1422973190884.1423118348921.2&__hssc=72727564.3.1423118348921&__hsfp=570112071)

You should firstly modify **package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "preferGlobal": "true",
  "directories": {
    "bin": "./bin"
  },
  ...
}
```

Create a directory called **lib** in your modules folder, and create **mypgk.js** inside of it.

Then create a script which gets command line params like this

```
var argv = require('optimist').argv;

if (argv.make === 'deploy') {
  //do some stuff here
} else if (argv.make === 'test') {
  //another stuff
}
//...
```

Then install it **install -g ./**

then you can use it **mypgk --make=deploy**

If you don't like to pass arguments like I did here you can change the way you do it, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js)

**P.S** Here is brief summary what you need to do, to more precise information refer to the link at the beginning (recommended)

Comment: Here I found this [interesting repo](https://github.com/andrewjmead/global-npm-seed)