# Execute external Javascript NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, eval, external

I would like to execute an JS file passed in argument in my NodeJS app (without require each others)

Example :

```
$ node myapp test.js
```

test.js

```
console.log("Do some work")
test();
```

myapp.js

```
var test = function(){ console.log("Test working");
here_execute_js_in_process.argv[2]();
```

I tried the simplest option, read file thanks to fs.readFile and eval resulted data :

```
    fs.readFile(script, function(err,data){
      if(err) console.log(err);
      eval(data);
    });
```

but didn't worked, have you got a any solution ?

Comment: In what way didn’t `eval` work? You might want to take a look at [`vm.runInNewContext`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_options), anyway.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test.js is good as is.

Slightly-modified myapp.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function include(inc) {
    eval(fs.readFileSync(inc, 'utf-8').toString());
}

console.log("Running myapp.js with arg[2]=[%s]", process.argv[2]);
var test = function() { console.log("Test working")};
if (process.argv[2])
  include(process.argv[2]);
```

Comment: Yes, wasn't so far indeed !

Comment: Note that the [with global] scope is now gone.  I've tested it and it still works as expected with the modification.

Comment: yep, I tested and edit your answer, thanks a lot Michael

Comment: I use this to separate my router's code into subsections, making things more manageable.