# Does JavaScript have a way of passing in arguments through the terminal line like ARGV in Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby, command-line, argv

I wrote a simple script in Ruby that accepts a file path as an argument from the terminal and then performs a task with that file.

EX:

```
files = ARGV

html = ""

file = File.open(files[0])

file.each do |line|
    html << line
end

code = html.gsub(/\s+/, "")
string = code.gsub(/"/, "'")

puts string
```

and from the terminal I can type `ruby file.rb ~/path/to/file` (the path is the argument being passed.)

Does JS have an argument vector like this?

Comment: If using NodeJS, YES. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js

Comment: in the browser, `document.currentScript.src` or arguably `window.location.href`

Comment: @Tushar I went with node and it works great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. JavaScript itself does not support this.