# How to import .json file as arguments to .js file and launch it using command line?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, shell, command-line

I have a .json file stored in a local directory on my computer.

data.json

```
{ 
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "bat"
}
```

I want to load data.json as arguments somehow into a .js file that I also have stored locally on my computer. Then run it.

app.js

```
var foo = "bar",
    baz = "bat"; // Somehow, I need to import these arguments from data.json
// Then do stuff with them...
```

app.js is a pure javascript file (without access to an HTML "wrapper" or any JS libraries like jQuery, etc.).

I would like to use one of the following to call app.js:

1. Command line / shell script (including but not necessarily node.js),
2. AppleScript (Mac OS X Yosemite v.10.10.1), or
3. [iMacros for Firebox bookmarklet](http://wiki.imacros.net/Bookmarklet).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What about updating `data.json`so that it looks like `data = { ... }`then  adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>` and then saying `var mydata = JSON.parse(data);`?

Comment: @fedorqui: I like the thought process. But would this really work as the question describes "without an HTML wrapper?" AFAIK, the `<script>` tag is only useable in HTML files not pure JS, correct?

Comment: Uhms, I guess you are right (I am not very familiar with JavaScript in general). Would this approach help you? [Load JSON file locally using pure Javascript](http://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript). It uses an XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using node, just require the json.

```
// app.js
var data = require('./data.json');
var foo = data.foo // etc
```

In your command line you can just run

```
node app.js
```

Of course if your data json is in a different directory, adjust the path accordingly. You could also allow it to use any json by providing it as an argument ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js))

Comment: I'm not using any library; op is happy with using node. please don't downvote just because you don't understand the question