# How to use node.js to access arguments from a .json file instead of command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

[This SO answer describes use of the `process.argv` variable to access command line arguments when using node.js to run a javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4351548/1640892).

[Here is the source documentation for `process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv).

But what if my arguments are stored in a .json file instead of input individually at the command line. Is there a way to also access them using node.js?

data.json

```
{ 
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": "bat"
}
```

I want to load data.json as arguments somehow into my .js file that I also have stored locally on my computer. Then run it.

app.js

```
var foo = "bar",
    baz = "bat"; // Somehow, I need to import these arguments from data.json
// Then do stuff with them...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can require your json file, and set your local values with required values.

Code will be like this:

```
var params = require('./data.json');
var foo = params.foo;
var bac = params.baz;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can :

```
var json = require('youjsonfile.json');

var foo = json.foo;
```