# How to run node script with a parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to run my node script and pass a parameter to this node script

for example my node script **index.js** looks like :

```
var user = "me";
console.log(user);
```

and I would like the user to be a parameter instead of using

> node index.js

I can use **node index.js --user foo** 
and the parameter pass to the script

Do you have any idea what I should use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass command line arguments to Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you are trying to pass command line arguments in Node. Check out this for multiple explanations on how to do that: [How do I pass command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js)
Seems like this would do if you only have one argument:

```
var user = process.args.slice(2)
console.log(user);
```