# How to pass a command line argument to a nested script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-scripts

**NOTE: This is NOT about sending args to the top-level script, but to the script called by *that* script**

In my package.json, when I call a script that takes command line args directly, it works. But when I call a script that calls that other script, it's not passing the command line args to it. How do i pass them?

```
{
    ...
    "takes-args": "somemodule",
    "calls-takes-args": "npm run takes-args"
}
```

When i run the below command, the args come through:

```
npm run takes-args -- -env dev
```

But when I run it through the other script, it never gets the args. Is there some way to pass them down? Maybe by a variable marker like a dollar sign?

```
//The top-level script gets the args, BUT takes-args does NOT
npm run calls-takes-args -- -env dev
```

Is there any way?

Comment: @adeneo This is NOT a duplicate. That's for passing args to the top-level script only.

Comment: Exactly, and your top-level script has to pass those values to the next one etc, there's no magic that passes args, you have to do it yourself. I'll remove the dupe, and see if anyone knows a different way of doing this though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass command line arguments to Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-node-js)

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: @tmslnz Sorry, I had the script commands typed in wrong above. You can see better what I'm trying to do now.

Comment: I am not seeing this behaviour with node v6.9.1. Can you confirm that the issue is seen with this version of node?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `scripts` field should look like this:

```
{
    ...
    "takes-args": "somemodule",
    "calls-takes-args": "npm run takes-args --"
}
```

Notice the `--` at the end of `calls-takes-args`.

Anything you pass after the `--` is directly appended onto the script you are running. When you run `npm run calls-takes-args -- -env dev`, that is the equivalent of running `npm run takes-args -env dev`. Of course, that does not work.

If you add the `--` to `calls-takes-args`, when you run `npm run calls-takes-args -- -env dev`, `npm run` runs `npm run takes-args -- -env dev`. Success!

If you don't pass any args to `calls-takes-args`, the trailing `--` won't hurt.

---

Edit:

If you can't/don't want to modify your `package.json`, you can run

```
npm run calls-takes-args -- -- -env dev
```

That will run `somemodule -env dev`.

Comment: You misread my post. :) I am running at the command line: `npm run calls-takes-args -- -env dev`. The "calls-takes-args" is a script defined in package.json that simply does `"npm run takes-args"`. I want it to pass the "-env dev" from the ***command line*** to the script *it* is *calling*.

Comment: @DonRhummy I believe you misread my answer. If you edit your scripts section to what I have posted above, you should be able to pass parameters from the command line, through `calls-takes-args`, to `takes-args`.

Comment: @DonRhummy OK, now I think I understand. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @DonRhummy Does my edited answer address your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't had a chance to test it yet (we're using a work around right now), but i'll try to get to this soon.

Comment: This worked! `{
    ...
    "takes-args": "somemodule",
    "calls-takes-args": "npm run takes-args --"
}`

Comment: What's the equivalence for this in `yarn`?

Comment: @SalahAdDin yarn does not require a `--` to pass arguments, so you shouldn't encounter the original problem with yarn. There's nothing special you need to do with yarn.